# Getting "Module not found" error when using SCSS with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I tried to add a scss style to my "Logo.js" component, and yet and can't manage to fix this error I keep getting:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/Logo/Logo.js 5:0-19

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'logo.scss' in '/Users/antonov/Project/HorlogeV2/src/components/Logo'
```

Here is my component:

```
import "logo.scss";


class Logo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="logo">
        <img alt="Logo failed 2 load" src='./Images/Soldierboi.jpeg'/> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Logo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import "logo.scss"` would look inside `node_modules` folder. Assuming `logo.scss` is in the same folder as `Logo` component, you should import it like this:

```
import "./logo.scss";
```